# Extension Chrome doesn't work immediately on the tab still loading the page or newly opened tab (need a few seconds to work)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. The way the extension works is that when you click on the extension icon, it will automatically copy the Shopee product links from all the currently open tabs. I tested the extension,  at the first time, the extension seems fine and work properly. I made 2 scenario, Increasing the number of tab links that match the criteria and also decreasing the number of tab links that match the criteria. i tested 2 tab match links and the extension work properly, but when i add 2-3 more tab match links immediately and click again the extension then paste in document, it only paste the first 2 tab match links. it needs a few more seconds around 3-5 seconds to work again when i click the icon extension. I follow the https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write instruction to copy to clipboard

here are the extension files:

## **Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Shopee Products URL Copier",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Copy Shopee Products URLs",
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
      }
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "clipboardWrite",
      "offscreen",
      "notifications"
    ],
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
}
```

## **Background.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  getAllOpenTabsLinks();
});

async function getAllOpenTabsLinks() {
  const urlPattern1 = /^https:\/\/shopee\.co\.id\/.*-i\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/;
  const urlPattern2 = /^https:\/\/shopee\.co\.id\/product\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
  const urlPattern3 = /^https:\/\/shopee\.co\.id\/xx-i\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/;

  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});

  const matchedArray = tabs
    .filter(tab => {
      return (
        urlPattern1.test(tab.url) ||
        urlPattern2.test(tab.url) ||
        urlPattern3.test(tab.url)
      );
    })
    .map(tab => tab.url);

  const urlList = matchedArray.join('\n');

  await addToClipboard(urlList);
  showNotification();
}

async function addToClipboard(value) {
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
      url: 'offscreen.html',
      reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.CLIPBOARD],
      justification: 'Write text to the clipboard.'
    });

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: 'copy-data-to-clipboard',
      target: 'offscreen-doc',
      data: value
    });
}

async function showNotification() {
    const notificationOptions = {
      type: 'basic',
      iconUrl: 'icon48.png',
      title: 'Shopee Link Copied!',
      message: 'Link Copied to Clipboard.'
    };
  
    chrome.notifications.create(notificationOptions);
}
```

## **Offscreen.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<script src="offscreen.js"></script>
```

## **Offscreen.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessages);

async function handleMessages(message) {

    if (message.target !== 'offscreen-doc') {
      return;
    }
  

    switch (message.type) {
      case 'copy-data-to-clipboard':
        handleClipboardWrite(message.data);
        break;
      default:
        console.warn(`Unexpected message type received: '${message.type}'.`);
    }
  }

const textEl = document.querySelector('#text');

async function handleClipboardWrite(data) {
    try {
      if (typeof data !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError(
          `Value provided must be a 'string', got '${typeof data}'.`
        );
      }
      textEl.value = data;
      textEl.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
    } finally {
      window.close();
    }
  }
```

Thank youu very much!

How to solve the problem?